# Маски в dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при редактировании ячейки в `dataGridView`, при вводе некорректных данных (например формат ячейки DATE, а вводятся буквы) выдавалось предупреждение?

А если вводится дата в формате 10122017, она переводилась бы в формат 10.12.2017.

База данных импортируется из SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы автоматически выдавалось предупреждение, достаточно задать нужный тип данных для привязанного значения.

Вариант с `DataTable`:

```
DataTable dataTable; // поле формы


// Где-то в коде
dataTable = new DataTable();
// Задаём столбцу тип DateTime
dataTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
// Грузим в таблицу данные
dataTable.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now);

// Привязываем к гриду
dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
// Задаём отображаемый формат
dataGridView.Columns["Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
```

Вариант с типизированной коллекцией:

```
public class Data
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

// Взять наиболее подходящую коллекцию.
// Может быть ObservableCollection, BindingList.
List<Data> data;

// Создаём и заполняем коллекцию данными
data = new List<Data> { new Data { Date = DateTime.Now } };
// Биндинг
dataGridView2.DataSource = data;
// Формат
dataGridView.Columns["Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
```

Однако, такие "предупреждения" не удобны для пользователей.

Нужно использовать события [CellValidating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating(v=vs.110).aspx), [CellValidated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidated(v=vs.110).aspx) и вручную [определять](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7ehy30d4(v=vs.110).aspx) желаемое поведение.

---

По поводу перевода из одного формата в другой на лету. Всё реализуемо, но тут возможны конфликты с заданным форматом вывода. Думаю, нужно обрабатывать события [CellFormatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) и, возможно, [EditingControlShowing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing(v=vs.110).aspx) - а далее работать с полученным [текстбоксом](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7568621/5045688).